# How to make a div so important so all things in the div stays in the same box

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have a basic div and I want it to be able to absorb all other css rules of other elements and just keep them inside itself.

Right now the scroller of my chat is left outside the div and makes the whole site unstable.
[image: the red shows the divs range]

Comment: You might be able to use an iframe instead of a div for this, or to restrict the contents use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: No, everything is in my code.

Comment: Could you post snippets of the position code? Without code we cannot do much.

Answer (score 0):

Give the element inside the div `overflow: hidden`, and give that div these properties:

```
div {
  all: unset;
  overflow: auto;
  width: ____; //or max-width
  height: ____; //or max-height
}
```

Comment: after I change overflow to hidden, the navbar is not showing up anymore.

Comment: Show some of your html and css, I can't understand how would these changes affect something outside of that div, unless you just copy pasted my answer instead of giving that div a class.